# Convert array of arrays into hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I transform `array1` into `hash1` in Ruby?

`array1` looks like this:

```
    [[80, "X", 12],
     [80, "X", 13],
     [80, "X", 14],
     [80, "X", 15],
     [80, "X", 16],
     [81, "Y", 20],
     [81, "Y", 21],
     [81, "Y", 22],
     [81, "Y", 23],
     [81, "Y", 24]]
```

`hash1` looks like this:

```
[['id' => 80, 'type' = >'X', numbers => {12,13,14,15,16}],
       ['id' => 81, 'type' = >'Y',numbers => {20,21,22,23,24}]]
```

Comment: That is invalid. It is impossible.

Comment: Your `hash1` isn't a hash, it's still an array.

Comment: Also, the format of `array1` is unclear. Is it guaranteed that those subarrays with the same `id` values have the same `type` values?

Comment: yes, same id have the same type!

Comment: "`hash1`" should be `array2 = [{ 'id' => 80,... 'type' = >'X', numbers=> [12,13,14,15,16] }, { 'id' => 81, 'type' = >'Y', numbers=>[20,21,22,23,24] }]`. Please edit. (That should prevent more downvotes and may cause some downvotes to be retracted.) When giving an example, it is helpful to explicitly assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `array1 = [[80..]`), as that allows readers to simply cut and paste.

Answer (score 7):

```
array1
.group_by{|id, type, _| [id, type]}
.map{|(id, type), a| {"id" => id, "type" => type, "numbers" => a.map(&:last)}}
# => [
#      {"id"=>80, "type"=>"X", "numbers"=>[12, 13, 14, 15, 16]},
#      {"id"=>81, "type"=>"Y", "numbers"=>[20, 21, 22, 23, 24]}
#    ]
```

Comment: You are [fasstttt !](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/superheroes/images/2/24/Flash.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140203094110)

Comment: @Wand, that's mainly because he uses Vim with a [Happy Hacking keyboard](http://www.amazon.com/Happy-Hacking-Keyboard-Professional2-White/dp/B000EXZ0V2). The HHK has special cooling circuits that prevent fast typists from overheating the keyboard.

Comment: @CarySwoveland No. I use emacs, not Vim.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) is used (as by @sawa), one can alternatively use the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged:

```
arr = [[80, "X", 12],
       [80, "X", 13],
       [80, "X", 14],
       [80, "X", 15],
       [80, "X", 16],
       [81, "Y", 20],
       [81, "Y", 21],
       [81, "Y", 22],
       [81, "Y", 23],
       [81, "Y", 24]]

arr.each_with_object({}) { |(x,y,z),h|
  h.update(x=>{ "id"=>x, "type"=>y, "numbers"=>[z] }) { |_,o,n|
    { "id"=>o["id"], "type"=>o["type"], "numbers"=>o["numbers"]+n["numbers"] } } }.values
    #=> [{"id"=>80, "type"=>"X", "numbers"=>[12, 13, 14, 15, 16]},
    #    {"id"=>81, "type"=>"Y", "numbers"=>[20, 21, 22, 23, 24]}]
```

Answer (score -2):

You would have to iterate through your array1 and start assigning values into the hash that you want using basic comparisons (if - else, group_by and mapping) and keeping history of the previous ids.

There's no such a ruby method that does this "magically".

Comment: This is pretty much stating the obvious.  Unfortunately, it does not help the person who asked the question.

Comment: Well its oviously not obvious to the person asking the question... Yes, fabianraf could have given an example, but he is correct that you have to iterate through the array.

Comment: Yes, holaymolay, I should have given an example. I'm glad someone else gave the exact code that works.